# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest with retry functionality

Tags: nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I have my main UI thread that calls `sendAsynchronousRequest` method of `NSURLConnection` to fetch data.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[self request] 
 queue:[NSOperationQueue alloc] init
 completionHandler:
        ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)       
        {
            if (error)
            {
               //error handler 
            }
            else 
            {
               //dispatch_asych to main thread to process data.
            } 
        }];
```

All this is fine and good.

My question here is, I need to implement retry functionality on error.

1. Can I do it in this block and call `sendSynchronousRequest` to retry as this is the background queue.
2. Or dispatch to main thread and let the main thread handle retry (by calling `sendAsynchronousRequest` and repeating the same cycle).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the request by calling `[self request]`. If `request` is an atomic @property, or is otherwise thread safe, I can't think of any reason you couldn't kick off a retry from a non-main thread.

Alternately, you could put a copy of the request into a local variable prior to your `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:` call.  If you do that, and then reference it in your completion handler, then it will be retained implicitly and `[self request]` will only be called once.

Generally speaking, this probably isn't a great pattern. If the service is down, absent some other checks, it will just keep trying forever. You might try something like this:

```
NSURLRequest* req = [self request];
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
__block NSUInteger tries = 0;

typedef void (^CompletionBlock)(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *);    
__block CompletionBlock completionHandler = nil;

// Block to start the request
dispatch_block_t enqueueBlock = ^{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:queue completionHandler:completionHandler];
};

completionHandler = ^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    tries++;
    if (error)
    {
        if (tries < 3)
        {
            enqueueBlock();
        }
        else
        {
            // give up
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //dispatch_asych to main thread to process data.
    }
};

// Start the first request
enqueueBlock();
```